# Automatizar tareas de cambio de permisos

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy intentando encontrar cómo hacer un script para automatizar cambios de permisos y luego programarlo con cron.

He creado un directorio en /home con un grupo y permisos determinados, y he añadido los usuarios a dicho grupo.

Como sabéis, si los usuarios crean directorios y/o archivos dentro de este directorio, heredarán dichos permisos y grupo. El problema llega cuando los usuarios "pegan" archivos ya creados, los permisos no cambian.

Quiero hacer que se ejecute una tarea que me cambie los permisos y grupo cada x tiempo, pero no sé cómo programarlo.

Imagino que tengo que hacer un script, de esto no tengo mucha idea, con lo siguiente:

```
sudo chgrp -R grupo /home/directorio
chmod -R 774 /home/directorio
```

Y luego programar ese script con cron.
El problema lo tengo con el script. No sé como escribirlo y aplicar permisos de root, teniendo en cuenta que se tiene que ejecutar en modo desatendido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haría falta saber qué versión de cron estás usando. Pero intentaré darte una explicación que sirva para cualquier versión.
Todos estos comandos son como superusuario :

Creamos el script :

```
echo "#!/bin/bash" > /usr/local/bin/cambiaPermisos.sh
echo "chgrp -R grupo /home/directorio" >> /usr/local/bin/cambiaPermisos.sh
echo "chmod -R 774 /home/directorio" >> /usr/local/bin/cambiaPermisos.sh
```

Hacemos el script ejecutable solo por el superusuario:

```
chmod 0700 /usr/local/bin/cambiaPermisos.sh
```

La siguiente línea es aplicable solo si estás usando vixie-cron.
Añadimos una línea a /etc/crontab para que ese script se ejecute cada 30 minutos :

```
echo "0,30 * * * *   root /usr/local/bin/cambiaPermisos.sh" >> /etc/crontab
```

Y ya está, vixie-cron reconoce automáticamente los cambios en /etc/crontab sin tener que ejecutar crontab.

Si usas un cron distinto de vixie-cron entonces no hagas la última línea y en su lugar haz lo siguiente.

Ejecuta como superusuario :

```
crontab -e
```

Te aparece un editor con el crontab actual. Añade la siguiente línea y cierra el editor grabando el fichero.

```
0,30 * * * *   /usr/local/bin/cambiaPermisos.sh
```

También puedes usar `crontab -e` con vixie-cron; pero la línea a añadir debe ser la anterior, la que incluye `root` tras los cuatro asteriscos.

Comment: Estoy en Linux Mint 17.2, se me olvidó ponerlo, y tengo instalado cron y anacron. Miraré vixie-cron. ¿Puedo suponer que se ejecutará sin solicitarme, cada vez, la contraseña de superusuario?

Comment: No veo práctico ejecutar `echo "..." >> /etc/crontab`. Es mucho más recomendable editar crontab con sus comandos, esto es, `crontab -e`.

Comment: @BeaSTR, no hace falta que te instales vixie-cron. Utiliza el que ya tienes. Usando `crontab -e` puedes editar la tabla de cron y añadiendo la línea que pongo al final ya te va bien; no te va a pedir la contraseña, de hecho cuando ejecute ni siquiera te vas a enterar de que lo hace. Ten en cuenta que si haces `crontab -e` como root entonces editas la tabla de cron de root y los comandos se ejecutaran como root; que en este caso es lo que quieres.

Comment: @fedorqui , yo también prefiero usar `crontab -e`. Pero para dar instrucciones es más claro con `echo` porque es lo mismo para todo el mundo. Con `crontab -e` las instrucciones a dar son menos completas; imagina que el único editor en el sistema es vi y que no sabe usarlo. Nótese que la solución con `echo` no vale para todos los cron, solo para los que estén preparados como vixie-cron.